# Adding a legend to a double plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to add a legend to my plot using ggplot in R. Everything OK so far. My case is special because I'm trying to deal with three variables, but not in order to draw a 3D plot but draw a 2D plot facing v1 vs. v2 and v1 vs. v3.

I get my plot in a correct way but I dont get the legend.

This is my code:

```
colfuncWarmest <- colorRampPalette(c("orange","red"))
colfuncColdest <- colorRampPalette(c("green","blue"))

plot <- ggplot(data=temperatures_Celsius, aes(x=temperatures_Celsius$Year))
params <- labs(title=paste("Year vs. (Warmest minimum temperature\n",
                      "and Coldest minimum temperature)"),
               x="Year",
               y="Coldest min temp / Warmest min temp")
theme <- theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) #Centering title
wmtl<-geom_line(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                aes(y=temperatures_Celsius$Warmest.Minimum.Temperature..C.,
                    color="red"
                ),
                colour=colfuncWarmest(length(temperatures_Celsius$Year))
              )
wmtt<-stat_smooth(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                  aes(y=temperatures_Celsius$Warmest.Minimum.Temperature..C.),
                  color="green",
                  method = "loess")

cmtl<- geom_line(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                 aes(y=temperatures_Celsius$Coldest.Minimum.Temperature..C.,
                     color="blue"
                  ),
                 colour=colfuncColdest(length(temperatures_Celsius$Year))
                )
cmtt<-stat_smooth(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                  aes(y=temperatures_Celsius$Coldest.Minimum.Temperature..C.),
                  color="orange",
                  method = "loess")


plot + theme + params + wmtl +  wmtt  +  cmtl +  cmtt
```

(Not all code was added because I did a lot of changes. It is only to get an idea) I get this:

[image: plot]

If I add

```
+ scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

(for example) in order to add the legend, I get no error, but nothing different happens. I get the same plot.

What I want is only two lines. A red one that says "Warmest minimum" and another blue line that says "Coldest minimum". What could I do to get my legend in this way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I would say that the correct way to apply a legend to a ggplot is to map a variable to an aesthetic (such as fill, color, size, alpha). Usually this consists of transforming the data to long format (key ~ value pair) and mapping the key variable to color or other aestetic.

In the current case this is not desirable since there is next to no chance the color gradient (`colorRampPalette`) on the line could be achieved. So I suggest a hacky way where a dummy layer (layer which will not be seen on the plot) is used to create the legend.

Here is some data

```
temperatures_Celsius = data.frame(year = 1900:2000,
                        Warmest = rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 5),
                        Coldest = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 5))
```

Your plot:

```
colfuncWarmest <- colorRampPalette(c("orange","red"))
colfuncColdest <- colorRampPalette(c("green","blue"))


plot <- ggplot(data=temperatures_Celsius, aes(x=year))
params <- labs(title=paste("Year vs. (Warmest minimum temperature\n",
                           "and Coldest minimum temperature)"),
               x="Year",
               y="Coldest min temp / Warmest min temp")
theme <- theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) #Centering title

wmtl<-geom_line(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                aes(y=Warmest),
                colour=colfuncWarmest(length(temperatures_Celsius$year)))

wmtt<-stat_smooth(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                  aes(y=Warmest),
                  color="green",
                  method = "loess")

cmtl<- geom_line(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                 aes(y=Coldest),
                 colour=colfuncColdest(length(temperatures_Celsius$year)))

cmtt<-stat_smooth(data=temperatures_Celsius,
                  aes(y=Coldest),
                  color="orange",
                  method = "loess")

plot1 <- plot + theme + params + wmtl +  wmtt  +  cmtl +  cmtt
```

Now add a dummy layer:

```
plot1+
geom_line(data = data.frame(year = c(1900, 1900),
                   group = factor(c("Coldest", "Warmest"), levels = c("Warmest", "Coldest")),
                   value = c(10, 20)), aes(x=year, y = value, color = group), size = 2)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it's difficult for me understand why using a new data.frame in `geom_line`. What you should expect using this is seeing a line drawn in the plot. But magically works. It only remains to say that you should use `aes(...,group=1)` in order to avoid a warning (another thing that I don't understand). For the rest, I've modified your code to my purpose and it works perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: @Carlos the philosophy of ggplot is that each layer should map all the data explained by a certain geometry. For this to be possible the data need to be structured in long format, so all values are in one column and another column contains the grouping variable (Warmest and Coldest in this case). By specifying `color = grouping variable` in the `aes` call the color mapping and the legend are created simultaneously and the legend is closely connected with the color mapping. When one specifies several geom line layers each with just one grouping variable no legend is created.

Comment: In this case one can make a legend by specifying yet another dummy layer which contains sufficient data for the legend but is not seen on the plot. Most of the time the correct solution is to restructure the data to long format, but in your case this is not true since then you could not be able to achieve the colorRamp gradient in one line.